# How do we add loading="lazy" via native JS?

Tags: javascript

If we create an image via JS:

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = imageSource;
image.alt = "Your text here";
image.width = '480';
image.height = '360';
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
  container.appendChild(image);
});
```

how do we add loading="lazy"?

So the final output is

```
<img src="" loading="lazy" width="480" height="360" alt="Your text here">
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the attribute like you have with the rest?

Comment: rtm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/loading